# Issue with Relative Import

Tags: python

I am having error in importing both via relative and absolute import. Something I have done many times in the past and it used to work.

here's my folder structure:

```
project
├── src
│   └── notebook.ipynb
    |_____ test.py
    └──  __init__.py
```

So basically within src folder (which is made a package using **init**.py) I have two files- notebook.ipynb and test.py

Now within notebook.ipynb, in cell I do:

```
from . import test
```

Gives the following error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[13], line 1
----> 1 from . import test

ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Even if I try absolute import:

```
from src import test
```

I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[14], line 1
----> 1 from src import test

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

Now I have used similar importing styles in past projects and it would work all fine. Within the same package I can either via relative or absolute. It doesn't NEED me to specify any PYTHONPATH in my env variable.

But this time it isn;t working.

I am using Python 3.9.15 on MAC OS installed within a conda env

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You should not put your notebook in your `src` folder. The proper way of working with package is to install them then use it as an external package (like you do with numpy, torch, pandas, matplotlib etc..).

Long answer: The [src layout](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/src-layout-vs-flat-layout/) is meant to contain only importable modules in Python. There are several reasons, I let you read the exhaustive and short list of reasons in the link. So basically your project tree should like this:

```
project
├── notebooks
│   └── notebook.ipynb

├── src
    ├── package_name
        ├── test.py
        └── __init__.py
```

I let you read the [short tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) to package your project.

Although, when you explore data, testing some processing and so on, this packaging step can be repetitive. It means that each time you make changes in your package you have to install it again and again. To solve this problem you can install it as a [editable package](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html).

**Note**: if you use a notebook to test / develop / use your package, you need to restart the kernel each time you make changes in your package though, editable mode set or not. If your package is not installed as editabled then you should restart the kernel and install the package for every change in your package's code.

**Note 2**: all links provided are from the official authority of packaging in Python. It does not mean this that it's the only way to go through it, but, at least, this is some common practices for clean Python project.

**Edit after the comment**: Also, you can use your text editor / IDE to change how Python will search for module. It will heavily depends of your editor / IDE. In my case, if I open the `project` VSCode and I set the working directory option as the opened folder, you can import what you want. Still, do not place your notebook in your `src` folder. Notebooks are not source file, even if they are going to by converted to script. If you use VSCode, I can add more details how to set it up as a workaround. But this way of working is not standard so I do not recommand it.

Comment: I am not creating an installable package. I just want to test out some code in notebook while importing some other code from a module in same or diff directory. Later i will convert the code in notebook to also a script. 

This used to work earlier. Not sure why it doesnt work now

Comment: First, I stay on the position of my post. What you are doing is a package. You have an `__init__.py`, this is a package from Python glossary. So there are two options:

1. You do not use the package structure at all. You only place your modules and your notebook in a single folder, no` __init__.py`. Then you can import using `import test`.
2. You follow the procedure suggested, or any other equivalent. The editable mode is exactly what is adapted for your situation. People use that also in testing a lot.

Last option, which is dirty, is to append python path in your notebook.